# Python change Windows Path (refresh Shell)

Tags: python, windows, variables

i have a Python script here and it is called from the Windows CMD. 
It is executing some commands and also changing the Windows environment variables. Now after i changed them with the command "setx". I have to restart another Shell so the new variables are loaded into it.

Is it possible that the main shell from which i called my script can update the variables itself ?

Or is it possible to start another shell with the new variables and the script will continue in the new opened shell ?

Thanks

Comment: Can we see the code better to know what's happening?

Comment: `setx` changes the value of the variables in the registry and broadcasts a [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725497) message that causes Explorer to reload its environment. So when you start a new cmd shell from Explorer it inherits the updated values. cmd itself doesn't have a message loop to listen for `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`.

Comment: You can update the current environment using the `os.environ` dict. This will be inherited by a shell spawned with `subprocess.call('cmd.exe')`.

Comment: So you mean i can call another shell with a subprocess and than update my env variables ?

Comment: The default behavior is for Python's current environment variables to be copied to the child process. You could also modify `environ = os.environ.copy()` and then use `subprocess.call('cmd.exe', env=environ)`. Another approach is to write out the values in a batch file that uses `set` commands (not `setx` in this case) that you can run in the parent cmd shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't change the value of a environment variable**.

Allow me to clarify: **environment variables represent the variables set on the environment of a process when that process starts**.

**From the point-of-view of the new process, its environment is unchanging**. Changing a variable on the environment (the process' parent) will *not* change the value of the environment variable seen by the process. Changing a variable on the process will *not* make it's environment see the change.

So, what *can* you change?

- Variables set on *your* process. This is achieved in python by changing `os.environ`, or using `set` on the shell. Any changes will be seen by your process and any children you make (`os.system`, `subprocess`, most commands on the shell).
- Variables set by the system (what `SetX` does). These changes will be seen by any new process launched directly by the system (Explorer, in Windows) *after* you change them.

Comment: @eryksun thanks, I didn't know about the message. I've edited the answer to clarify

Comment: Why do you say you can't modify variables in the environment of a process? What do you think modifying `os.environ` does if not that? It calls `os.putenv`. See [`_putenv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83zh4e6k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and the underlying Windows API [`SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686206) on MSDN.

Comment: You can certainly modify the variables on *your* process - but the OP is focusing on getting the values of newly changed variables *outside* the process, which is why I stressed that specific point. It's certainly arguable, but I think it might aid comprehension. I've made the answer a community wiki, please feel free to make the changes you find appropriate

Answer (score 2):

Each process has its own environment. When a process starts another process, the new process gets a (eventually modified) copy of its parent environment.

The rule is :

- a process can modify its own environment - this modifications will be inherited by child processes started later
- a process can modify (at start time) the environment of its child processes
- a process can never modify its parent's environment (*)

So when you start a Python script from a `cmd.exe` :

- the script can change its own environment and those changes will be visible by all subsequent commands of the script and all its children
- the script cannot change the environment for its parent `cmd.exe` nor for subsequent commands of that `cmd.exe`

If you need to execute other batch commands after changing the environment, you will have to start a new `cmd.exe` for the python script and have this new shell execute the other commands, or directly execute a `.bat` file (both via `subprocess`module).

---

`setx` is a completely different thing : it updates the default environmnent that is given to processes started from windows explorer (including cmd.exe). That environment is stored permanently in Windows registry, and every change to it is broadcasted to all active processes ... that monitors it. Any windows GUI application *can* process it (and explorer does - that's how every explorer window know immediatly what is the current default environment), but console applications normaly do not.

---

(*) well it used to be possible for `.com` executable in old MS/DOS system and was even documented. It should be possible on Windows recent system through `WriteProcessMemory` API call but is absolutely non documented (thanks to eryksun for noticing)